# missing header file on a new installation of visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I just installed visual studio 2012 and tried running my C++ project on it.
compilation fails due to missing "SDKDDKVer.h", "windows.h", etc.

I installed the windows 8 sdk from [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx), but after successfully running the installer with the default components (including the windows headers), I can't find any include folder under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0 or C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A.
I ran the SDK installer twice + tried to repair and still I can't find any trace of the windows header files.

Did anyone encounter something similar?

what am I missing? my OS is win7 x64. I uninstalled VS2010 before installing VS2012.

thanks,

Comment: Any specific reason you uninstalled VS2010? They can exist side-by-side without any issues.

Comment: I just checked my installation and for some reason, the most current Windows.h I have is in Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Include/um.

Comment: @Timo Geusch thanks! my VS points by default to $(WindowsSdkDir)include == C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include. I wonder what the um stands for, and how it is working correctly on your computer.

Comment: the issue seems to be related to: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762015/include-and-libraries-directories-not-setup-correctly-for-c-if-vs2010-already-installed bug opened on the 9/10/2012. hope they get to it soon.

Comment: Just an update: the bug was closed by MS as "not reproducible". To me this says "bad QA" or a company that doesn't really care about its customers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a [bug caused by VS2012 using the configuration of VS2010](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762015/include-and-libraries-directories-not-setup-correctly-for-c-if-vs2010-already-installed).

You have to manually fix the include libraries to get around this (through the property manager).

The substantial modifications needed are :

1. adding `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` to the include paths
2. adding `$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)` or `$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)`
   to    the library path  depending if your building for x84 or x64.

Comment: Could you please expand on how you fixed it with the property manager? Because I'm facing the same problem, but also the Update 1 fails on the Visual C++ installation missing..

Comment: @Geerten Sure: Open property manager (view -> property manager), select one of your projects and under debug->win32 you will see the property sheets being used by your projects. right click + properties and in VC directories make sure the include directories contain "$(WindowsSdkDir_71A)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir_71A)include"

Comment: btw - you will need to do it once for x86 and once for x64 (select an x64 project if you have any) and repeat the process for it as well).

Comment: thanks, but I already fixed it by uninstalling everything related to 2010 and 2012, and also scanning the registry for anything that was in there. After that, a clean install of 2012 came out working :)

Comment: @Geerten ouch. I really like MS products, but sometimes they just make stupid decisions. Fixing this bug seems like a day work (20 min dev + the rest for QA). By the time they get to it it won't matter. Had a similar issue with the installation of MS SQL 2012. MS need to understand that bugs related to install should have a higher priority during the initial life cycle of a product.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the contents of your include directories?  I've been trying for 3 hours to get something to compile but it is still complaining and I'm really lost as to what folders need to be included for VS2012 to be able to find "windows.h" and "rpc.h" in particular

Comment: @JeffTucker here: I use property sheets (those includes are not shown here) on top of the basic directories:
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
$(WindowsSdkDir_71A)include
$(FrameworkSDKDir_71A)include

Comment: I have this problem, but sadly this solution isn't working for me. Even pasting the absolute path to the include directory fails at build time - although the IDE finds it ok when using right-click>open document!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem also exists when you upgrade a VS2010 project to VS2012.

To me, manually fixing the include dirs (see step 1 in previous answer) took care of the problem.