# I can't include <iostream> in Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Few months ago I installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.
Beacuse of some school projects, I had to install Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition.
Now, when I try to compile a project in Visual C++ 2010, I cannot include any usual header
like `<iostream>`, `<cmath>`, etc. The folder the compiler searches is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include.

But all these include files are located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include.

Can someone please explain me what is about with these two paths (what are the differences)
and how to solve the `#include <iostream>` problem.

Comment: The Visual Studio 2010 version should come with its own headers, there shouldn't be any reason for you to use the newer version (which may lead to subtle problems down the road; also if you could use the newer compiler/libraries to begin with, why not stay with VS2012?). Probably the best to just reinstall the express edition, strange error.

Comment: Show your project configuration (Include directories)

Comment: Include directories: $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;

Comment: I reinstalled VS2010. Same problem.

Comment: If you need a free IDE there are a few less cr@ppy options out there.

Comment: <quote>But all these include files are located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include.</quote>
That is the include directory of VS2012, not VS2010.

Comment: Please look if this solution helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770400/missing-header-file-on-a-new-installation-of-visual-studio-2012  
This is a known compatibility problem between 2010 and 2012.

Answer (score 2):

From the details you share, I understand that /Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include directory doesn't contain the standard header files.

The include directory $(VCInstallDir) in VS 2010 is probably pointing at /Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC. Since, the include folder is empty you don't get to compile your code.

As far as I know, this problem occurs when people install VS2012 and 2010 afterwards. My guess some problem occurs with registries and VS2010 Setup doesn't install header files properly.

You might have 4 options:

1. Using Visual Studio Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt, change the $(VCInstallDir) such that it points to "/Visual Studio 11.0/include"
2. If you know someone who has VS2010(same edition as yours) working properly, copy their "/VC/include" directory to yours.
3. Uninstall both VS2012 and VS2010 ( full uninstall as described here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) Clean the registries and install VS2010 again.
4. Make a fresh Windows installation and install VS2010 afterwards.

Sadly only option 4 worked in my case. Option 2 worked too, but I got other problems in another project. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. A fresh Windows and VC++ 2010 Express install on a virtual machine solved the problem.