# Visual studio express 2012 cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When I run my project I get fatal errors:

```
 Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
 Cannot open include file: 'd3d11.h': No such file or directory
 Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory
```

I have installed SDK, someone tell that I must set correct path to SDK directory, but I not know where to do it, in `Tools->Options->Projects` and solution I see `"Option has been deprecated"`

Comment: Maybe you should refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770400/missing-header-file-on-a-new-installation-of-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 1):

@Kanglai may be right here but the error you are seeing related to the D3D headers is something different. The DX SDK ships separately from the Windows SDK. See this article on MSDN.

[Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The way Visual C++ handles directories has changed in recent versions, hence the deprecated message. The following blog post explains the changes and how to do the same thing in the newer versions of VS.

[VC++ Directories](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx)