# Obtaining wchar.h and other header files

Tags: windows-7, header, visual-studio-2012

I've downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Pro from dreamspark and was all happy about it, but it looks like I'm missing the `wchar.h` file (isn't it kind of essential to Windows applications? Why didn't I get one?).

I feel stupid because I couldn't simply Google the solution (no magic "to get `wchar.h` download this SDK and do this", but some obscure problems with SP1 version)

Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to visit this link: [missing header file on a new installation of visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770400/missing-header-file-on-a-new-installation-of-visual-studio-2012)

According to that link, there is a bug and there is a workaround found at: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762015/include-and-libraries-directories-not-setup-correctly-for-c-if-vs2010-already-installed

Comment: Finally I manually unpacked .msi files from installation disc, all the files were there. Weird bug though