# can't setup openGL superBible examples due to problems finding Windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to compile the examples from the book OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition.
I got everything from their git repository and I'm trying to open it using Visual studio 2013 by opening the visual studio 2013 solution file that is included.
When I try building the main project inside "sb6_vs2013" It claims it can't find Windows.h : "Error 2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory"

Now I tried to look at people's solutions on the internet and couldn't find anything helpful.
If I right click on the project and go to properties -> Configuration Properties - > VC directories I can see that it has the line:
$(WindowsSdkDir)\include
When I click on Macros I can see the path of WindowsSdkDir, its pointing to the right place where Windows SDK is, which in my case is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1" if I look at my file system in that folder and go to "\Include\um\" I can find Windows.h there, but for some reason visual studio 2013 fails to find it.
I thought it was due to bad installation and I even went as far as re-installing windows, visual studio and everything (it was time for that anyway) but nothing seems to fix this problem, even the new fresh installation didn't do the trick.

I'm not sure what else I can do to make this work.
Could someone help me solve this issue once and for all?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770400/missing-header-file-on-a-new-installation-of-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I managed to solved it, after the reinstall all the macros were correct I just need to check "inherit from parent on project defaults" checkbox and it did the trick