# Why does 'iprtrmib.h' in Window Kits 8.0 reference 'mprapidef.h' in window 'kits 8.1'?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (Update 5) with MS Window Kits 8.0 and .NET Framework 4.5.51209. Recently, I also installed MS Window Kits 8.1.

Now, I have a file: '\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\iprtrmib.h' that failes to include 'mprapidef.h'.

That include file only exists at: '\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\mprapidef.h', which is not in my include path.

My Visual Studio 'Include Directories' is set to: "$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);".

These are my Visual Studio macros:

- VCInstallDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\
- WindowsSDK_IncludePath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt

When searching, I found a slightly similar question: [missing header file on a new installation of visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770400/missing-header-file-on-a-new-installation-of-visual-studio-2012)

I tried repairing my Visual Studio installation. I do not want to change the 'Include Directories' for each of my projects. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed vs2015 and vs2012, then the same problem occurs,however, I find a solution.

open visual studio project settings,click VC++ Directories, find Include Directories,add the following line to it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
```

Answer (score 0):

One may add the corresponding 8.1 paths to the environment variable.
Maybe it's necessary to do the same thing with the lib environment variable (WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86).